# Is it possible to change the brighness on the fly for Adafruit_CircuitPython_NeoPixel

Tags: python, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython, neopixel, adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel

Is it possible to change the brightness on the fly for Adafruit_CircuitPython_NeoPixel ?

It seems to be possible in a C library but no in python.

Thanks,
mcb

Answer (score 0):

`neopixel` derives from `Pypixelbuf`, and inherits a `brightness` property from that module.  Did you try it?

Comment: Well, I only can set the brightness when I initiate NeoPixel: 
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(
    pixel_pin,
    pixel_width * pixel_height,
    brightness=0.1,
    auto_write=False,
)

and I use PixelFramebuffer. Here I could not  find any brightness setting

Comment: Did you try `pixels.brightness = 0.75`?  I can't try this, but looking at the base class source, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deinit() the pixel object and reinitialize it with the new brightness.

```
pixel.deinit()
pixel = neopixel.NeoPixel(pixel_pin, number_pixel, brightness=new brightness)
```